# Numba Dict(): find key of the minimum value in Dict

Tags: python, dictionary, numba

Assuming that I can pre define a numba typed dict() as:

```python
testDict = numba.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=numba.types.unicode_type,value_type=numba.types.float64)
```

for ex:

```python
testDict={'A1':1.1,'B2':1.2, 'C3':1.3, 'D4':1.4}
```

is it possible to find the key for the minimum value of the dict as in the python mode?

```python
minkey=min(testDict, key=testDict.get)
```

Comment: You can just iterate over the `testDict.items()` and locate the key where the minimum is by storing the minimum-so-far and its associated key. Note that dicts are inefficient for this kind of operation because they are implemented using hash-maps (sparse data structure). This is especially true for large dict. Using a sorted array can be faster regarding the use-case. Numpy provide basic functions for that (like `searchsorted` and `argsort`) also available in Numba. Also please note that Numba tends not to compute string efficiently yet.

Comment: Hi @Jerome, in this case the ```dict()``` is being used for implementing a sort of "switch-case" which allows me to limit my calculations from four to just one costly vector angle evaluation.  The dict() will always contain four float values based on which I need do only a subset of calculations for the variable containing min value.

Answer (score 1):

The easier succinct way is:

```python
return sorted([(val, key) for key, val in testDict.items()])[0][1]
```

This is valid for my case as I have to deal with only four key-value pairs. Otherwise for longer dicts, [Jerome's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75139835/numba-dict-find-key-of-the-minimum-value-in-dict?noredirect=1#comment132598298_75139835) would be applicable.